# Yoast SEO meta description not saving

Tags: yoast

I generate a Focus Keyphrase and Meta Description in Yoast SEO meta box for my Home Page. But when I exit the editor, if I go back to the Home Page, the Focus Keyphrase and Meta Description have disappeared.

Does anyone know how I can keep them?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the issue? I'm currently having the same problem, and I'm finding there is JS console error in the page editor `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerPlugin')`. I've spent a couple hours tryin to patch up their JS in the post-edit.js file to no success as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I spent easily 5 hours trying to track down and fix an issue with Yoast meta fields not saving properly. The only real clue I had was this console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerPlugin') at window.wpseoScriptData.window.wpseoScriptData.featuredImage.i.registerPlugin (post-edit.js)
```

[Based on this Yoast Github issue](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/16885#issuecomment-830054436), it appears that the needed `YoastSEO` javascript app is not there when it's being called in `/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/js/dist/post-edit.js` when the page is loading, and Yoast javascript app is not actually there, so it bonks.

So there may be something somewhere that is dequeuing the needed javascript that builds the `YoastSEO` object. One thing to check is to search your code base (excluding the Yoast plugin itself) for instances of `wpseo`, `yoast`, etc. If you find some code that is dequeuing/removing something, that might be it. If you have a plugin with results, deactivate if you can and check if that fixes anything.

I also noticed that the SEO Analysis drawer never loads and has the loading spinner running indefinitely. The javascript that controls the setting fields seems to work, but when you save it doesn't actually save, it just goes into the void.

All that said... I wasn't able to figure out what was wrong, but I did get it to start working again. Here's what worked for me...

After reading through a lot of different issue threads, I stumbled across some issues around security plugins blocking parts of the install process. I have my Wordfence settings dialed up pretty strict, so I deactivated it per recommendations while we go through re-installing Yoast.

After making sure that your security plugin(s) are deactivated, then deactivate and uninstall Yoast. Apparently you don't need to remove the plugin data, just uninstall. (This is also a good time to update other plugins if you haven't already).

Once you reinstall Yoast, you should have a button available to reindex the "indexables" that you need to click. It might be on the Dashboard, I don't remember. If you don't see it, you might go to Search Appearance > General > Rewrite tables > Force rewrite titles and Enable that, then save changes. I'm not 100% positive, but it seemed like after I did that, there was a panel in the General settings Dashboard or something, that said something along the lines of "Looks like some settings have changed, you should re-index your indexables now" with a button to start the process.

I also had to turn "Show SEO settings for Posts/Pages?" back on under Search Appearance > Content types. After I reinstalled, those were disabled. So maybe that helped Yoast know to load the javascript properly.

I'm not super familiar with Yoast, as you can probably tell, but after doing all this, it's working.

I believe you can also trigger the reindexing process from the CLI if you want, and that it's recommended if you have a large site with over 10k posts or whatnot.

Hope all this helps!

Comment: Hi Shane. Thanks for your help. What do you mean when you are talking about "to reindex the "indexables" that you need to click".  What are the indexables? Thanks